# R: Filtering out non numerical values in dataframe

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have the following dataframe from a .csv file which consists of more rows but in order to keep it simple I've narrowed it down to those three. You can also access the csv file here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16277659/filter.csv

```
NAME;       YEAR;   VALUE
SAMPLE1;    1969;   6
SAMPLE1;    1970;   -6
SAMPLE1;    1971;   -7
SAMPLE1;    1972;   =-X
SAMPLE1;    1972;   ST
SAMPLE1;    1972;   3
SAMPLE1;    1975;   -7
SAMPLE1;    1976;   3
SAMPLE1;    1977;   3
SAMPLE1;    1978;   0
SAMPLE2;    1991;   -15
SAMPLE2;    1992;   =X
SAMPLE2;    1992;   -58
SAMPLE2;    1994;   -40
```

What I'd like to do is the following: I sometimes have qualitative values (like =-X, ST etc) which I don't necessarily want to loose but if there is a numerical value for the same year (in SAMPLE1 1972 =-X and ST), I would like to keep only the numerical value and get rid of the other values.

How would you do this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If one of these solutions meets your needs, please kindly select one of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And here's a `data.table` solution

```
dat <- read.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16277659/filter.csv", sep = ";")

library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, .SD[, ifelse(any(grepl("\\d", VALUE)), 
                          grep("\\d", VALUE, value = T), 
                          VALUE)], 
                          by = YEAR]
##    YEAR  V1
## 1: 1969   6
## 2: 1970  -6
## 3: 1971  -7
## 4: 1972   3
## 5: 1975  -7
## 6: 1976   3
## 7: 1977   3
## 8: 1978   0
## 9: 1991 -15
##10: 1992 -58
##11: 1994 -40
```

Answer (score 7):

I haven't mastered regex, so my mind first goes here:

```
dat <- read.csv2("filter.csv", as.is=TRUE)
dat$IsNum <- !(is.na(as.numeric(dat$VALUE)))

> dat
      NAME YEAR VALUE IsNum
1  SAMPLE1 1969     6  TRUE
2  SAMPLE1 1970    -6  TRUE
3  SAMPLE1 1971    -7  TRUE
4  SAMPLE1 1972   =-X FALSE
5  SAMPLE1 1972    ST FALSE
6  SAMPLE1 1972     3  TRUE
7  SAMPLE1 1975    -7  TRUE
8  SAMPLE1 1976     3  TRUE
9  SAMPLE1 1977     3  TRUE
10 SAMPLE1 1978     0  TRUE
11 SAMPLE2 1991   -15  TRUE
12 SAMPLE2 1992    =X FALSE
13 SAMPLE2 1992   -58  TRUE
14 SAMPLE2 1994   -40  TRUE
```

From there it's a simple matter of checking if `IsNum == TRUE`

Comment: Afterword you can just do `dat[dat$IsNum, ]`. The problem with this though, is what happens if he only has qualitative value for a certain year?

Answer (score 3):

The approach offered by @akrun will filter our any record in which there is a non-numeric in `VALUE`

The following will simply replace all of those values with `NA` (your post suggests you do not want to lose these records - just get rid of the text values).

```
dat <- read.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16277659/filter.csv", sep = ";")
dat$VALUE <- as.numeric(as.character(dat$VALUE))
dat

> dat
      NAME YEAR VALUE
1  SAMPLE1 1969     6
2  SAMPLE1 1970    -6
3  SAMPLE1 1971    -7
4  SAMPLE1 1972    NA
5  SAMPLE1 1972    NA
6  SAMPLE1 1972     3
7  SAMPLE1 1975    -7
8  SAMPLE1 1976     3
9  SAMPLE1 1977     3
10 SAMPLE1 1978     0
11 SAMPLE2 1991   -15
12 SAMPLE2 1992    NA
13 SAMPLE2 1992   -58
14 SAMPLE2 1994   -40
```

Answer (score 2):

From your posting, it seems like if there are only `non-numeric VALUES` for a particular YEAR, keep it, for example, if I change the last entry to "ST"

```
dat$VALUE[14] <- "ST"
indx <- with(dat, as.logical(ave(VALUE, YEAR, FUN=function(x) 
          {x1 <- grepl("\\d+", x); x2 <- grepl("[[:alpha:]]", x); if(all(x2)) x2  else x1})))
 dat[indx,]
 #     NAME YEAR  VALUE
#1  SAMPLE1 1969      6
#2  SAMPLE1 1970     -6
#3  SAMPLE1 1971     -7
#6  SAMPLE1 1972      3
#7  SAMPLE1 1975     -7
#8  SAMPLE1 1976      3
#9  SAMPLE1 1977      3
#10 SAMPLE1 1978      0
#11 SAMPLE2 1991    -15
#13 SAMPLE2 1992    -58
#14 SAMPLE2 1994     ST
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be:

```
data <- read.csv("filter.csv", sep=";")
data[!grepl("[A-Za-z]", data$VALUE),]
```

And the output is

```
      NAME YEAR VALUE
1  SAMPLE1 1969     6
2  SAMPLE1 1970    -6
3  SAMPLE1 1971    -7
6  SAMPLE1 1972     3
7  SAMPLE1 1975    -7
8  SAMPLE1 1976     3
9  SAMPLE1 1977     3
10 SAMPLE1 1978     0
11 SAMPLE2 1991   -15
13 SAMPLE2 1992   -58
14 SAMPLE2 1994   -40
```

Comment: This is incorrect in a case if he only has a qualitative value for a certain year (without any numerical values too)